# OSGi Import-Package: did I get the wrong package?

Tags: dependencies, osgi, apache-felix, equinox, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to use an OSGi bundle, but it's stuck in the "Installed" state and won't resolve. When I try to start it, I get the following message:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.apache.felix.gogo.usocklistener [6]
    Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.command; version="0.7.0.SNAPSHOT"
```

Here is my current list of bundles:

```
START LEVEL 6
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|OSGi System Bundle (3.10.100.v20140909-1519)
    1|Active     |    4|OSGi Release 4.2.0 Services (3.4.0.v20140909-1519)
    2|Active     |    4|OSGi Release 4.2.0 Utility Classes (3.3.0.v20140909-1519)
    3|Active     |    4|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.14.0)
    4|Active     |    4|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.12.1)
    5|Active     |    4|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
    6|Installed  |    4|Apache Felix Gogo USockListener (1.0.0.SNAPSHOT)
    7|Installed  |    4|Apache Felix Web Management Console (4.2.3.SNAPSHOT)
    8|Active     |    4|Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.8.1.SNAPSHOT)
    9|Active     |    4|Apache Felix EventAdmin (1.3.2)
   10|Active     |    4|Console plug-in (1.1.100.v20140828-1547)
   11|Active     |    4|Log Service Bundle (1.2.300.v20140828-1634)
   12|Active     |    4|Http Services Servlet (1.1.500.v20140909-1612)
   13|Installed  |    4|Jetty Http Service (3.0.200.v20140828-1634)
   15|Active     |    4|servlet-api bundle (2.4.0.SNAPSHOT)
```

So, obviously I need the `org.osgi.service.command` bundle, of at least v0.7.0 (it is "at least", and not "exactly", right?). But I have `org.eclipse.osgi.services-3.4.0` bundle, and it's active. If that doesn't contain the command bundle I need, then I don't know where to look.

Does `org.eclipse.osgi.services-3.4.0` include `org.osgi.service.command`? If not, where can I find `org.osgi.service.command` (preferably in source form rather than binary form)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a package:

- Visit http://search.maven.org
- Go to advanced search
- Type the name of the package to the "Classname" search field

Here is the result: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.osgi.service.command%22

Based on the result, you can find the original project or you can download the source jar.

Comment: thank you for this! i think this is the second time you've helped me with OSGi.